# How to map long to IList<long>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I have two classes which is **AccountSubscription** and **AccountSubscriptionDto**. 
I need to map "AccountNumber" to "AccountList" as collection of AccontNumbers (IList).

```
public class AccountSubscription : BaseEntity
{
    [Required]
    public int CustomerNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long AccountNumber { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class AccountSubscriptionDto : BaseDto
{
    [Required]
    public int CustomerNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public IList<long> AccountList { get; set; }

}
```

Here is what i did for mapping AccountNumber to AccountList.

**AutoMapperProfile.cs**

```
    CreateMap<IList<AccountSubscription>, IList<AccountSubscriptionDto>> ()
        .ConstructUsing(list => list.GroupBy(g => new { g.CustomerNumber })
            .Select(s => new AccountSubscriptionDto
            {
                CustomerNumber = s.Key.CustomerNumber,
                AccountList = s.Select(t => t.AccountNumber).ToList()
            }).ToList()
        );
```

When I run my application and use get AccountSubscription Method, I got this error as result:

```
"error": "Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
PagedList`1 -> IEnumerable`1

WestCore.Shared.Collections.Pagination.PagedList`1[[WestCore.Domain.Entities.PCsbins.AccountSubscription, WestCore.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] -> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[WestCore.AppCore.Models.PCsbins.Account.AccountSubscriptionDto, WestCore.AppCore, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"
```

**Edit**: Here is how do i call mapper in my application,

```
return DomainResult<IPagedList<AccountSubscriptionDto>>
.Success(_mapper.Map<IPagedList<AccountSubscriptionDto>>(await _repository.
GetPagedListAsync(pageIndex, pageSize, cancellationToken: ctx)));
```

Comment: Can you show how you are calling the mapper there? From the error it seems that you are constructing an `IEnumerable` while having an `IList` mapping configured.

Comment: Look at exception.ToString(). Because the error you posted here is useless.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to map `PagedList` instead of `IList` to `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @poke3 I've updated my entry, added function call...

Comment: Do you want to map object before `IPagedList` or after `IPagedList`?

Answer (score 1):

You configure `CreateMap<IList<AccountSubscription>, IList<AccountSubscriptionDto>>`, but you need `_mapper.Map<IPagedList<AccountSubscriptionDto>>`

try to configure `CreateMap<IPagedList<AccountSubscription>, IPagedList<AccountSubscriptionDto>>` like

```
CreateMap<IPagedList<AccountSubscription>, IPagedList<AccountSubscriptionDto>>()
    .ConstructUsing(source => source.Items.GroupBy(g => new { g.CustomerNumber })
        .Select(s => new AccountSubscriptionDto
        {
            CustomerNumber = s.Key.CustomerNumber,
            AccountList = s.Select(t => t.AccountNumber).ToList()
        }).ToPagedList(source.PageIndex, source.PageSize, source.IndexFrom)
    );
```

But, for this way, the page size will change due to that you groupby the source data.

In general, you should group by the source data before `ToPagedList`. You may consider query and group `AccountSubscription` first, then call `ToPagedList`.